# Using Regex.Replace() to replace a list of words fails

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace words in a long string with some HTML-tags. I seem to miss something when trying to do this for multiple words from a List, it does however work nicely for single Words.

Here is what i tried:
For testing purposes i reduced and altered the string to this:

```
string strTest = "Ein toller Testtext mit Folge und Folgen sowie Folgen<p> und <p>Folge und Cauchyfolgen und Cauchy-Folgen und Folgeerscheinungen und Folgendem";
```

The following code was used as a text to replace "Folge" with "WOW":

```
strResult = Regex.Replace(strTest, "\\b" + "Folge" + "\\b", "WOW");
```

This resulted in: `"Ein toller Testtext mit WOW und Folgen sowie Folgen<p> und <p>WOW und Cauchyfolgen und Cauchy-Folgen und Folgeerscheinungen und Folgendem"`, which is the desired result for a single word.

The following code resulted in the same, but is using my list of Objects, where "strWort" is the word i want to replace. Note the Value of listTooltips[39].strWort is "Folge".

```
strResult = Regex.Replace(strTest, "\\b" + listTooltips[39].strWort + "\\b", "WOW");
```

In the next step i tried to do this for the whole list. So i did the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listTooltips.Count(); i++)
{
    strResult = Regex.Replace(strTest, "\\b" + listTooltips[i].strWort + "\\b", "WOW");
}
```

The result is an unchanged String. And i am lost as to why. As noted it does work if i only put one Word to replace, even if i use a specific object from my list. So i am quite sure the code for the list is not wrong, at least not completly.

Additional things i tried:

- putting the value of each word into a seperate string and using that for the Regex.Replace. Failed.
- using a MessageBox.Show() to display the value of listTooltips[i].strWort to make sure, everything outputting as expected.
- using Regex.Match to check if the above code actually finds anything and yes, it does find everything. It just does not replace ist for some reason.
- not using Regex and going the string.replace-method instead. This is working with the above loop, but is causing differend unwanted results due to missing a filter / matchmode. i.e. "Folgen" is getting replaced to "WOWn" ect.

Really wondering WHY this is behaing as it does mainly, to better understand it. But id love a solution as well of corse :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you're always performing a `Regex.Replace()` on the original text `strTest`.

You need to call it on the previously-replaced text in `strResult`, otherwise each replacement (except for the very last one) will be overwritten with the original text.

Try this:

```
string strResult = strTest;
for (int i = 0; i < listTooltips.Count(); i++) {
    strResult = Regex.Replace(strResult , "\\b" + listTooltips[i].strWort + "\\b", "WOW");
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was a silly mistake on my side. I actually got that string strResult = strTest line in my code, but did not think about putting strResult in the Regex.Replace. Thanks alot!